# Javascript Library to Parse Dates Including RFC3339 & twitter format in IE? (jQuery or otherwise)

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, date, internationalization

Does anyone know of a js library that will parse all dates. (new Date should theoretically do this, but it doesn't, at least not in all browsers).

It should add support for ISO8601 / RFC 3339
And twitter formatted dates don't seem to work in IE either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I quite like [DateJS](http://www.datejs.com/).

Seems to support pretty much everything I've thrown at it.

Comment: Thanks, though it's a pretty big library with a lot of functionality I don't need. Perhaps I'll be able to extract it.